# Sqoop import table parameter in quotes failing

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc, sqoop, hana

I am trying to import data from SAP Hana database into hadoop using sqoop import command, but its failing by giving table name like "hadoop::Poc.Emp". HANA is case sensitive so table name should be in "".

```
sqoop import --connect "jdbc:localhost --username user --password pass --table "hadoop::Poc.Emp"

Execute getColumnInfoRawQuery : **SELECT t.* FROM hadoop::Poc.Emp AS t WHERE 1=0**
sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "::Poc": line 1 col 17 (at pos 17)
```

I want command like    `SELECT t.* FROM "hadoop::Poc.Emp" AS t WHERE 1=0`

Somehow i got this by using escape

```
- sqoop import --connect "jdbc:localhost --username user --password pass --table \"\"hadoop::Poc.Emp\"\"
```

it worked  - `Execute getColumnInfoRawQuery : SELECT t.* FROM "hadoop::Poc.Emp" AS t WHERE 1=0`

But then this Error came -

```
Finished writing jar file /tmp/sqoop-user/compile/dc0865e35ce739f216bd542d71222201/"hadoop::Poc.Emp".jar

Import failed: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: "hadoop::Poc.Emp%22
```

Can anyone please help me here?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what type of object is 'hadoop::Poc.Emp'?  Did you verify the name using HANA client tools?
Are you trying to import to Hive or only to the /user/ directory in HDFS?

Comment: 'hadoop::Poc.Emp' is a table name. I just want to import into /user/ directory

Comment: I do not think that is a valid table name in HANA, or at least for Sqoop as a table name.  Try a table name without '.' and '::'

Comment: It is a valid one. Format is like namespace followed by context followed by table name and i know without '.' and '::' it will work but as per the current structure of DB this is our limitation